# How do you style an image in an <a> tag?

Tags: html, css

Here's some code that contains `a` tags, one which contains an image.

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#">Not styled</a>
    <a href="#"><img src="image.png"></a>
</div>
```

If I only want to style the image, how would I do it (without creating a class or something similar)?

For example, if I want to style all the `a` tags, I could use the following CSS:

```
.container a {
    /* styles here */
}
```

If I want to style all the `img` tags, I could use this:

```
.container img {
    /* styles here */
}
```

Is there a way to apply this same logic to an `img` in an `a` tag?

Edit: Here are the styles I'm applying. For some reason, when I use `.container a img` it adds extra padding/margins.

```
.container a {
    padding: 9px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

Edit 2: I think the problem lies elsewhere. Whenever I try any of the suggested responses (i.e. `.container a img`, `#img`, `src="image.png"`) they all lead to the amount of vertical padding/margin increasing. Should I delete my post? It seems all it is getting is downvotes right now.

Comment: Sure, `.container a img`

Comment: What style are you trying to give to your image? Can you post the css of the image styling too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You can do that, Have a look into the demo, it will be applied to all the **images** under `a` tag

```
.container a img {
    /* styles here */
}
```

---

If you just want a single image to be applied for css, try giving it an ID, then apply css to an id

**Demo which applies to all**

```css
.container a img{
    filter: sepia(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="#">Not styled</a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://www.whistler.com/images/placeholders/200x200.gif" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://www.whistler.com/images/placeholders/200x200.gif" /></a>
</div>
```

**Demo which applies to single id**

```css
#img{
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="#">Not styled</a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://www.whistler.com/images/placeholders/200x200.gif" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://www.whistler.com/images/placeholders/200x200.gif" id='img' /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a nested CSS

```
.container a img {
    /* styles here */
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing something else wrong, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Can you post your styles? And what you want to achieve. Maybe it has something to do with it

Comment: All I have is padding. If I set both padding and margins to 0 with this code, there still seems to be some padding/margin, but it works fine if I just use `a`.

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

`.container a img {}` is the best way to do it, but every IMG will use the amount of padding/margin that you've given in the `.container a {padding: etc }`. So try to position the IMG with margins.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use CSS to point exactly to the image like below:

```
img[src="image.png"]{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your question: If I only want to style the image, how would I do it (without creating a class or something similar)?

Now, if you only want that specific image no problem, but if later more and more images will behave the same way you better create a class 
note: you didnt specify what styles you wanted for the image, so I asummed you wanted this ones ***padding: 9px 10px 5px 10px***

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#">Not styled</a>
    <a href="#"><img style="padding: 9px 10px 5px 10px;" src="image.png">YES styled</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your image a seperated class and then style it in your css

Answer (score -1):

You just to need to write CSS with a in heirarchy as

```
.container a img {
// your code
}
```

Comment: and your example will affect every `img` under `a` in complete page, not just in `.container` `div`.

Comment: This was just a explanation for adding hierarchy. You can use .container as a parent if you want to affect only img tags inside container class